# vectorize array from dictionary with tuple as key

Tags: numpy, dictionary

This is a very simple task, but somehow, I can't seem to figure it out.

Let's say I have a dictionary

```
dictr = {(0,1,2): 0, (5,4,2):1}
```

And an array:

```
A = [[0, 1, 2], [5, 4, 2]]
```

I am looking to get an array b = [0, 1]

I thought we could do it by:

```
B = np.vectorize(dictr.get)(A)
```

However, this is not working. Anyone knows why?

Comment: `np.vectorize` passes scalar elements of `A` to `get`, not pairs or tuples.  Sometimes `vectorize` is convenient, but it does not help with speed.  And often it is hard to use correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your dictionary keys are **tuple**, meanwhile the items in A are **list**.
You should convert all the element inside A to tuple so the key may match

A python-ic way (without numpy) might seems like this (considering every item in A matches a key in dictr)

```
b = [dictr[tuple(item)] for item in A]
```

Comment: Remember that this code will produce error if there is an element in A which doesn't match with a key in dictr, so make sure to check it if you are not sure about the condition ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `dictr.get` is called for elements of A, not for A's rows.
It calls `dictr.get(A[0,0])`, next `dictr.get(A[0,1])`, and so on. Each of elements of `A` is a scalar not present in the dictionary thus `np.vectorize` fallbacks to `None`. That is why you get 2x3 array of `None`.